# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB - while using clob in regexp_substr function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, clob

I am trying to use CLOB variable in regexp_substr function as below

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Tab_DATE = SYSDATE
WHERE Tab_ID IN (
    select regexp_substr(clob_variable,'[^~]+', 1, level) from dual
    connect by regexp_substr(clob_variable, '[^~]+', 1, level) is not null
)
```

`clob_variable` is of type CLOB and contains ~ separated ids.

While executing the update statement I am getting below error:

`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB`

Can we use CLOB with RegExp? If not, is there any way to convert CLOB values to tabular format?

Comment: Q: Can we use CLOB with RegExp?  A: No.  Q: There any way to convert CLOB values to tabular format?  A: So you want to apply a regex to a *table*???  A: what you *can* do is convert the CLOB to a string.  For example, `SELECT dbms_lob.substr( my_clob, 4000, 1 ) FROM my_table;`

Comment: Thank you.. but if I convert CLOB to string, will it take all the values? I want to generate temp table from CLOB variable. As my CLOB has ~ separated ids. Further I will use this temp table in update statement.

Comment: You CANNOT apply a regex to a CLOB.  I suggested one alternative, Barbaros Özhan gave you another.  SUGGESTION: You might want to revisit your data design.  It sounds like the stuff you're putting in a CLOB probably should have been separate columns and/or separate tables in the first place :(

Comment: Is tab_id of number datatype? What's your oracle version?

Comment: @paulsm4 regexp_substr supports clob: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm but it returns clob

Comment: @ Sayan Malakshinov - The fact remains this appears a flagrant misuse of CLOBs. I would strongly encourage the OP to revisit their data design :(

Comment: @paulsm4 I wouldn't call it data design, since that was just clob variable, not a column, but - yes, it's much better to use collections for such things. Thanks for mentioning it,I'll add this into my answer

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov is correct, this is not a DD issue as I have to pass large string which contains ~ separated ids (of type number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Tab_DATE = SYSDATE
WHERE Tab_ID IN (
    select replace(dbms_lob.substr(regexp_substr(clob_variable,'[^~]+~', 1, level)), '~', '') from dual
    connect by dbms_lob.compare(regexp_substr(clob_variable,'[^~]+~', 1, level), empty_clob() ) != 0
)
```

Comment: This is working also it has less conversions compare to what @SayanMalakshinov has provided.

Comment: This takes 10 minutes in Oracle to get executed for 1600 ids. Any way we can create chunk in Oracle SP itself?

Comment: If you want a better performing software I think you should use PL/SQL, extract your Ids from the clob and bulk update your table.

Comment: that is exactly what the select inside update is doing.

Answer (score 1):

the data should be converted to string(`CHAR` or a numeric type considering `Tab_ID` column as an `INTEGER` within this case) from `CLOB` such as

```
UPDATE TableName
   SET Tab_DATE = SYSDATE
 WHERE Tab_ID IN
       (
        SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(clb, '[^~]+', 1, level))
          FROM (SELECT clb
                  FROM t -- the other table with CLOB column
               CONNECT BY level <= CEIL(DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(clb) / 4000))
       CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(clb, '~') + 1
           AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL 
       )
```

Comment: Getting....ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Comment: can you share the sample data @TechTurtle ..?

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072157/how-to-convert-long-string-to-clob

Comment: Thank you Barbaros, can't paste string here so I have to create new Question as mentioned above.

Comment: So I don't have column as CLOB, it is a variable. Further, in your example, where should I put my CLOB variable? is it ```clb```?

Comment: It would be hard to handle such a long variable, rather try to insert into a table [such as](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1f16f96c9eded2ad344555d6c15fd4e4) @TechTurtle

Comment: Ok, I will try that and let you know. Not sure if we can create temporary tables in Oracle - but I guess it should be possible.

Comment: You can create temporary tables(*remains only during the session*) in Oracle if it matters @TechTurtle

Comment: but I still have to parse it, right? as the temp table will hold ` separated values in one column, one row.

Comment: sure @TechTurtle , that's your preference whether to hold parsed as integers within a table, or parse whenever needed through such a query. Btw, it's very late here(about3:00AM), need to go to bed :), lately I'll be able to respond,see you.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan you have few errors in your query example: 1. your subquery `(SELECT clb FROM t  CONNECT BY level <= CEIL(DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(clb) / 4000)` should fail because of infinite loop (that you are trying to avoid in parent subquery using `prior sys_guid is not null`; 2. the same subquery just returns duplicates of `clb` (looks like you tried to split clob by 4000 chars); 3. you don't need to split CLOB, regexp functions work fine with CLOBs; 4. length() also supports CLOBs, so you don't need dbms_lob.getlength

Comment: also not mistake, but it would be better to avoid: `prior sys_guid() is not null` - that is too old workaround for avoiding infinite loops in `connect by` and such behaviour was never documented, while there are many other newer and more standard methods, for example recursive subquery factoring, laterals  or multiset(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

`regexp_substr` returns CLOB in case of your first input parameter is CLOB, but you can't compare CLOBs' content with anything using `in` or `=`. So you need to convert your returned CLOBs to the data type of your `TAB_ID`.

So if your TAB_ID is number type, it should be:

```sql
UPDATE TableName
SET Tab_DATE = SYSDATE
WHERE Tab_ID IN (
    select to_number(to_char(regexp_substr(clob_variable,'[^~]+', 1, level))
    from dual
    connect by level<=regexp_count(clob_variable, '[^~]+')
)
```

and if your TAB_ID is varchar2 or char:

```sql
UPDATE TableName
SET Tab_DATE = SYSDATE
WHERE Tab_ID IN (
    select to_char(regexp_substr(clob_variable,'[^~]+', 1, level)
    from dual
    connect by level<=regexp_count(clob_variable, '[^~]+')
)
```

**Update:**
It's much better to use collections for such things, instead of concatenated strings. Just create own collection, for example:

```sql
create or replace type numbers as table of number;
/
```

And bind you list of numbers as a collection, so you query will look like this:

```sql
select * from tablename where id in (select * from table(:numbers))
```

Example of using collections in queries:

```sql
SQL> select * from table(numbers(1,2,3,4));

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           1
           2
           3
           4
```

Comment: Using collection: not sure how can I bind, as the list of numbers will be passed as a parameter to the SP.